# How to trigger action when rails session expires?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user who can login to my Ruby on Rails application. I wrote the functions myself with an sessions controller. I also set a time in session_store.rb when the session should expire.

This all works fine, But additionally I want to track when users login or logout. Right now I can trace the login and logout when it's done manually by the user. But when a session expires my "sessions#destroy" option is not triggered and therefore no logout time is set.

Is there any possibility to trigger an action when the session expires or when a session is killed by rails?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I should have included some of my code:

```
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    if !current_user.nil?
      redirect_to start_path
    end
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      UserTracing.create(user_id: user.id, sign_in_at: DateTime.now)
      redirect_to start_path, notice: I18n.t("text logged_in")
    else
      flash.now.alert = I18n.t("error username_or_password_invalid")
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @id = current_user.id
    session[:user_id] = nil
    UserTracing.where(user_id: @id).order(sign_in_at: :asc).last.update_attributes(sign_out_at: DateTime.now)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: I18n.t("text logged_out")
  end
end
```

Comment: How are you storing your sessions?  I don't know if it is entirely possible if there is no request occurring to the server when their session expires.  If the session is stored in a cookie for instance, thats browser stuff and no request, thus there isn't a real way to track it.  You would have to maybe make a chrome extension to do that.  But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I added the code of my sessions controller to clarify how I create and delete my sessions.

Comment: If you're using the cookie session store (which is the default) then you have no good way of knowing when the session expires. In fact, out of the box it expires whenever the site visitor happens to quit her browser, so it is impossible for you to know.

Comment: ya, so it looks like you are using cookie storage for your session.. there is no way to track when it expires I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy.

All you have to do is use your sessions helper method to

1. Create a time when the session is set to expire 
   sessions[:expires_at] = Time.now + minutes_to_run * 60
2. Create a function that retrieves this time.
3. Have a function in your controller that is run before this page is loaded to check if the current time is greater than the time the session was set to expire. The solution uses javascript setTimeout() to ensure the page is refreshed otherwise you would have to wait for the user to reload. This way your app refreshes the page.

Here's a blog post that details this idea.
https://medium.com/@thatlovelypract/rubyonrails-timed-session-a5de0cf70f3b

Comment: The linked page no longer exists